# Use Geofence transition to trigger separate array

Tags: android, arrays, geolocation, sharing

I have a number of geofences with which I am hoping to trigger samples upon entry.

currently I have to arrays set up with the geofences and their corresponding samples. The geofence setup I am using has come straight from the google location demo so at the moment is set up to create a notification upon transition. What I would like to do is have a set up where geofence(2) triggers sample(2)

Currently my samples are in a list that is in a separate activity from my geofencemain class and my geofence transitionsintent class so I would like to know the best method to get the data from the geofence transition into the right class and would also love help with knowing what to do with the data once I have got it in order to make it trigger an individual item within an array or list.

Please let me know if I can provide any more detail which might help with this question and thanks very much for any and all help!